# Vertical Align mixed elements within li elements

Tags: html, css, alignment

Long time reader, first time post :)    Any good ideas for this? :

I have 4 `<li>` elements displaying as inline-block.

These elements each contain a mix of elements. 
3 contain an `<h3>` and a `<div>`. 
1 contains an `<q>`, a `<strong>` and a `<a>`.

My question: how can I vertically align the text of these elements without placing any restrictions on the amount of text within, or without knowing the amount of text within in advance? As the text length increases, shorter columns drop with the bottom of the `<ul>` when I want them to remain at the top!

the code and result can be viewed here:
http://jsfiddle.net/m6HG5/5/

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give us a sample of what your code currently looks like? You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to make things simple.

Comment: post all of your markup, please!

Comment: oops....have edited my post accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am understanding your question properly, you need to specify the line-height of your UL element:

```
<ul>
    <li><h3>List Item 1</h3></li>
    <li><strong>List Item 2</strong></li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the styling:

```
 ul {
        line-height:1em;
    }

li {
    float:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
}

h3 {
    font-size:1.5em;
}

strong {
    font-weight:bold;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m6HG5/3/

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this locks the ul into a fixed height, when I want it to expand as necessary. I just want short blocks to remain at the top!